# How to stop a thread

Tags: android, flashlight

I am using Thread to blink the flash light.

It works great for first time when i click on blink button.

**Can any one tell me how to stop the blinking.**

Here is my code :

```
blink.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {

                    long blinkDelay = 500; // Delay in ms
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {

                            mCamera.startPreview();
                        } else {

                            mCamera.stopPreview();
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    mainlayout.invalidate();
                }
                          }
        });
```

Comment: I think it's better to use timer/countdowntimer to achive what you want. To interrupt thread use .interrupt.

Comment: @user3041975 NP :) Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your flashlight is controlled by a button, simply check the boolean status (on or off) of the button each iteration. You can then let the thread exit naturally once all work inside the thread had been completed.